# Jquery - a way to reuse same code multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS functions that looks like :

```
$('#div1 input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if(this.value=='YES'){
        $('#field1').show();
    }else{
        $('#field1').hide();
    }
});

$('#div2 input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if(this.value=='YES'){
        $('#field2').show();
    }else{
        $('#field2').hide();
    }
});

$('#div3 input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if(this.value=='YES'){
        $('#field3').show();
    }else{
        $('#field3').hide();
    }
});
```

As they are much similars, there is a way to improve them in less code?

Thanks

Comment: add a common class to each of the divs and target using that.

Comment: It's possible to do it by targeting just input[type=radio] and then exploding $(this).attr('id') but there might be a more efficient way to do it if you show your HTML

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is the following. I replaced the if-else hide/show with toggle. I also used `===` for true type/value comparison.

```js
function changeToggle(inputSelector, fieldSelector, value) {
  $(inputSelector).change(function() {
    $(fieldSelector).toggle(this.value === value);
  });
}

changeToggle('#div1 input[type=radio]', '#field1', 'YES');
changeToggle('#div2 input[type=radio]', '#field2', 'YES');
changeToggle('#div3 input[type=radio]', '#field3', 'YES');
```

#### Using a Loop

```js
$("*[id^='div']").each(function(index, div) {
  var id = $(div).attr('id').match(/^\w+(\d+)$/)[1];  
  $(div).find('input[type=radio]').change(function(e) {
    $('#field' + id).toggle(this.value === 'YES');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is how I would do this. I support this route.

Comment: but what if there are 500 divs like this on the page?

Comment: @Krishna: I added a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using attribute begins with selector, `.closest()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\D/g` to match digits in `id` of closest element where `id` begins with `"div"`

```
$("[id^=div] input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    var n = $(this).closest("[id^=div]")[0].id.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (this.value=="YES") {
        $("#field" + n).show();
    } else {
        $("#field" + n).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using custom attributes is much better way or if you're in HTML 5 you can use data-attributes. See example below:

```
<input type="radio" data-show="#field1" />
<input type="text" id="field1" />

<input type="radio" data-show="#field2" />
<input type="text" id="field2" />

<input type="radio" data-show="#field3" />
<input type="text" id="field3" />
```

JS:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var targetEl = $(this).data('show');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {        
        $(targetEl).show();
    }else {
        $(targetEl).hide();
    }
});
```